# Are the keys in a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> immutable?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, generics

I get a `Dictionary<string, string>` back from an API but depending on certain rules need to modify some of the key names.

Before I head down the road of copying to a new `Dictionary` I just wanted to confirm that the keys in a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` are immutable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right, if the key changes, you will need to remove the entry with the old key and insert a new entry with the new key.

If only some of the keys change, you don't need to copy the entire dictionary. Both Add and Remove operations on `Dictionary` are roughly O(1) operations.

Answer (score 7):

It is more like that **you** have to make sure that the type you use for `TKey` is immutable if it is a reference type. String is immutable, by the way. Value types **can** be mutable, but you don't get the opportunity to modify the stored key in the `Dictionary`.

Comment: Only the `GetHashCode` value and the equivalence class defined by `Equals` need to be immutable.  Note that a suitable equivalence class is defined for all class types--reference equality--and indeed that is generally the only equivalence class which should be used for mutable objects.  There is nothing whatsoever wrong with having a mutable class type as a dictionary key if the purpose of the dictionary is to associate instances of that type with something else.

Answer (score 3):

The keys in a Dictionary<string, string> are immutable.

For instance, the following code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("One", "1");
dict.Add("Two", "2");

var k = dict.First();
k.Key = "Three";
```

Will throw the following compiler error:

> Property or indexer
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair.Key'
>   cannot be assigned to -- it is read
>   only

That being said, a Dictionary<T, T> *may* have mutable keys if you use a reference type, see:

[C# Dictionary<> and mutable keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007296/c-dictionary-and-mutable-keys)

(I know, I know, strings are reference types... but the link above will explain...)