# What can you use as keys in a C# dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, types, custom-type

I come from a python world where only hashable objects may be used as keys to a dictionary. Is there a similar restriction in C#? Can you use custom types as dictionary keys?

Comment: Theoretically you can use any type as a key. In practice it should be an immutable type, otherwise you'll be in a world of pain when keys start mutating...

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek Note [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917298/are-the-keys-in-a-dictionarytkey-tvalue-immutable#comment16656400_3917393) -- "Only the GetHashCode value and the equivalence class defined by Equals need to be immutable. A suitable equivalence class is defined for all class types--reference equality--that is generally the only equivalence class which should be used for mutable objects. There is nothing whatsoever wrong with having a mutable class type as a dictionary key if the purpose of the dictionary is to associate instances of that type with something else. "

Comment: @ChrisW reference equality ought to be good enough for mutable objects in some applications, I agree. Indeed, it would be the superior implementation. However there is the situation where you receive an object over a network or from a file, then you have no choice but to construct a similar object to be used as a key into a Dictionary, so you have to resort to equality based on the immutable fields of a mutable object.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The requirement for a dictionary key is that it is comparable and hashable.  That's turtles all the way down in .NET, every type (other than pointer types) derives from System.Object and it is always comparable thanks to its Equals() method.  And hashable thanks to its GetHashCode() method.  So any .NET type automatically can be used as a key.

If you want to use your own type as the key then you only need to do something special if you want to re-define object identity.  In other words, if you need the ability for two distinct objects to be equal.  You'd then override the Equals() method, typically comparing fields of the object.  And then you must also override GetHashCode(), equal objects must generate the same hash code.

If the type cannot be changed or you want to customize the behavior especially for the Dictionary then you can pass a custom IEqualityComparer<> to the constructor.  Keep in mind that the quality of the hash code you generate with your own GetHashCode() determines the dictionary efficiency.

Comment: Maybe a better term than "comparable" is [equitable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - The word is "equatable", not "equitable". Equitable means something being treated fairly. Equatable is something comparable that can be equal.

Comment: @Enigmativity you are right, thanks. The name of the interface is [`IEquatable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1). Possibly my spell-checker "corrected" my text to *equitable* when I wrote that comment. I'm blaming it to software. :-)

Comment: Yep, I call it "autocorrupt" when I'm typing stuff. "Equatable" seems to be a mathematical speciality word and most spell checkers are convinced you should speak English, and not maths!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the important thing with keys is that they implement (or have a good default implementation of) `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. The `Dictionary<T, K>` implementation can take advantage of generic `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

All custom types will come with a default implementation of `GetHashCode` and `Equals` because these are members of `object`, however, that default might not always be relevant to your type.

The dictionary first attempts to get the hash code to determine the bucket the value will land in. If there is a hash collision, it falls back onto equality (I *think*).

Do note that the type of key you use (`class`, `struct`, primitive type, etc) can yield different performance characteristics. In our code base we found that the default implementation of `GetHashCode` in `struct` wasn't as fast as overriding it ourselves. We also found that nested dictionaries perform better in terms of access time than a single dictionary with a compound key.

Comment: I suppose if you use the obvious definition of equality (ie. objects are equal if all fields are equal), the default Equals and GetHashCode are good enough? (except maybe for performance reasons, but I'm not there yet)

Comment: @static_rtti The default implementation of equality for a `class` is not field-equal, it's reference equal I think. For a `struct` I believe it's value equal over the first x-byte block or something arcane like that. Personally I'm a fan of making sure the implementation is well defined for custom types as keys, but at the same time we have few instances where custom types are keys.

Comment: @static_rtti Not necessarily, all reference types use reference equality by default.

Comment: You're right about performance, Value types GetHashCode default implementation uses reflection to get the values of the type's fields (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx). It's very slow. On the other side that gives you a pretty good default behavior.

Comment: @CharlesBarthélemy Yes the default is actually as you would expect, by its value, which is fortunate. I never realised it used reflection.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, just implement interface IEqualityComparer, override GetHashCode and Equals.

Comment: So you have to do it all by yourself? Is there something to help you implement the hashing function?

Comment: `GetHasCode` is a funny name for a method. Default implementation is `return false;` :)

Comment: @static_rtti: `System.Object` has a default implementation of GetHashCode() that's probably simply based on the object's address (or maybe some kind of ID in case of garbage collection). Some other objects, like `System.String`, override it to return something related to their contents. And for all other cases, you can use an implementation of `IEqualityComparer` to customize the hashing. Look at the `StringComparer` class for example: Each of its members has a different implementation of `IEqualityComparer` to match the string comparison, so you can have, say, case-insensitive hashing.

Comment: @Suhan You don't actually need to implement that interface, but it is arguably a Good Thing to do.

Comment: When I've had to implement `IEqualtyComparer`, I usually just have to delegate the `GetHashCode` call to something else, like an identifier or string.  Rarely have I had to generate a hash-code myself.  Obviously this depends on the object being stored.

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth You also don't need to implement IEnumerable for using iterators, but it is more obvious

Comment: @Suhan I know, but your answer as it stands implies that it is *required*.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add that, these days, you can use C# `record` types as keys.

The benefit of `record` (instead of `class`) is that it now implements `GetHashCode()` etc. for you automatically (via compiler-generated magic).

- For details see [Records (C# reference) -- Value equality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#value-equality)
- Beware this Help doesn't say explicitly that you can use them as keys (but I believe you can)
- Beware that I expect that Bad Things Would Happen if you mutate (change a property value of) an object that's being used as a key, so don't do that