# Dictionary does not contain key despite Comparer.Equals returning true

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, equality

I've been hunting down a bug where I have a dictionary that insists on saying a key does not exist, despite its comparer actually saying that it does. For example, in the following snippet, the exception is thrown:

```
if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
{
    var comparer = dictionary.Comparer;

    foreach (var _key in dictionary.Keys)
    {
        if (comparer.Equals(key, _key) &&
            comparer.Equals(_key, key) &&
            comparer.GetHashCode(key) == comparer.GetHashCode(_key) &&
            comparer.GetHashCode(_key) == comparer.GetHashCode(key))
        {
            throw new Exception("Key exists, but dictionary doesn't find it");
        }
    }
}
```

The dictionary is a generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` with the default equality comparer (empty constructor). The `TKey` class implements proper `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods.

Is there anything I might be missing here? I'm at a complete loss!

Comment: Did the hash code change after you added it to the dictionary?

Comment: Of which type is the key?

Comment: As usual true [MCVE] would have exposed the issue... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007296/c-sharp-dictionary-and-mutable-keys can probably be considered duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way this could happen is if the key is mutable, and its content has been changed after it has been inserted into the dictionary.

Here is how it happens:

- You insert a key into a dictionary; the dictionary gets its hash code, and puts it into a corresponding hash bucket, resolving conflicts by calling `Equals`
- You mutate the key; now its hash code no longer corresponds to its hash bucket
- You call `ContainsKey`. The dictionary looks for the key in its new bucket. Since the key is not there, `false` is reported
- When you iterate the dictionary, all keys are returned, including ones that are no longer in their legitimate buckets. That's why you get a hit in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: That was indeed the case! `GetHashCode` depended on a mutable property. It was driving me mad, thank you!