# Modify struct variable

Tags: c#

Assume I have a struct Point with public int's x and y. I want to change a value and I can. But once I store it in a dictionary, I can no longer do so. Why?

MWE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public struct Point
    {
        public int x, y;

        public Point(int p1, int p2)
        {
            x = p1;
            y = p2;
        }
    }

    public static void PrintPoint(Point p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{{x: {0}, y: {1}}}", p.x, p.y));
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var c = new Point(5, 6);
        PrintPoint(c);                                          // {x: 5, y: 6}

        c.x = 4;  // this works
        PrintPoint(c);                                          // {x: 4, y: 6}

        var d = new Dictionary<string, Point>() 
        {
            { "a", new Point(10, 20) },
            { "b", new Point(30, 40) }
        };

        foreach (Point p in d.Values)
        {
            PrintPoint(p);  // this works
        }

        PrintPoint(d["a"]); // this works                       // {x: 10, y: 20}

        Console.WriteLine(d["a"].x.ToString());  // this works  // 10

        // d["a"].x = 2; // why doesn't this work?
    }
}
```

How come I can access the struct variables when it's in a dictionary but can no longer change them? How do I change them?

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil

Comment: Because `d["a"]` returns a temporary copy that you aren't storing anywhere. Modifying a temporary wouldn't make sense

Comment: It "does not work" because the compiler complains. The text of that complaint is relevant.

Comment: One way to solve this is to assign a new `Point` with the new `x` value and the same `y` value to the dictionary item: `d["a"] = new Point(2, d["a"].y);`

Comment: One comment from a design point of view: If you're going to have a constructor that takes values that are used to set properties (or fields in this case), it's helpful to the clients of your class/struct to make the constructor argument names the same as the property names so they understand what they're setting. For example: `public Point(int x, int y) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I agreed to close this as a duplicate. Ultimately, I just changed `struct` to `class` and now it's a reference type that's stored on the heap instead of a value type stored on the stack: problem solved. Thanks again!

Comment: @RufusL thanks, Rufus - I agree re:design. This actually looks nothing like my real struct, it's just a MWE.

Comment: Ah, cool. Because i was also going to comment that there's already a pretty robust [`Point Structure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point(v=vs.110).aspx) available in the `System.Drawing` namespace (source code for it is [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Point.cs,a041be61667d4c9a))

Comment: @RufusL I did not know that! Thanks for sharing! My actual struct (now a class) stores data on installers for a program that installs a bunch of software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong with what you're trying to do.

In 99.999999999% of cases, structs should be readonly.  See Microsoft design guidelines https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/struct

> X DO NOT define mutable value types.
>
> Mutable value types have several problems. For example, when a
>   property getter returns a value type, the caller receives a copy.
>   Because the copy is created implicitly, developers might not be aware
>   that they are mutating the copy, and not the original value. Also,
>   some languages (dynamic languages, in particular) have problems using
>   mutable value types because even local variables, when dereferenced,
>   cause a copy to be made.

You should also not mutate an object that is being used as a dictionary key.  Dictionaries are based on hash values, and if you change a field of the key, you will change its hash value. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3007334/4415493

> The Dictionary type makes no attempt to protect against
>   the user modifying the key used. It is purely left up to the developer
>   to be responsible in not mutating the key.
>
> If you think about this a bit this is really the only sane route that 
>   Dictionary can take. Consider the implication of doing an
>   operation like a memberwise clone on the object. In order to be
>   thorough you'd need to do a deep clone because it will be possible for
>   an object referenced in the key to also be mutated and hence affect
>   the hash code. So now every key used in the table has it's full object
>   graph cloned in order to protect against mutation. This would be both
>   buggy and possibly a very expensive operation.

Comment: Unless I missed something, the OP is not mutating a dictionary key, are they?

Comment: No, but the OP is trying to change the item stored under that key - and there he gets a copy

Comment: @HansKesting Right, but half of this answer is about not mutating an object used as a key...

Comment: First part makes sense (+1), but I am not trying to change the key.

Comment: I think my question should be closed as a duplicate, but I'm going to accept this for now because the OCD part of me wants to see 1991 points become 2,000 :P - thanks for help for real though!

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary value is a Point object. So, you can update the key with a new Point object.

```
Right Way (Update):
            d["a"]= new Point(5, 20);
            PrintPoint(d["a"]);
            Console.WriteLine(d["a"].x.ToString());

Round About: (Remove and Add)
            d.Remove("a");
            d.Add("a", new Point(2, 20));
            PrintPoint(d["a"]);
            Console.WriteLine(d["a"].x.ToString());
```