# KeyNotFoundException in C# Dictionary after changing property value based on what, the GetHashCode is calculated. Why?

Tags: c#, dictionary, hash

See the code below.

```
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
    // Create Dictionary
                var dict = new Dictionary<TestClass, ValueClass>();

    // Add data to dictionary
                CreateSomeData(dict); 

    // Create a List
                var list = new List<TestClass>();
                foreach(var kv in dict) {
    // Swap property values for each Key
    // For example Key with property value 1 will become 6
    // and 6 will become 1
                    kv.Key.MyProperty = 6 - kv.Key.MyProperty + 1;

    // Add the Key to the List
                    list.Add(kv.Key);
                }

// Try to print dictionary and received KeyNotFoundException.
                foreach (var k in list)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{dict[k].MyProperty} - {k.MyProperty}");
                }
            }



    static void CreateSomeData(Dictionary<TestClass, ValueClass> dictionary) {
        dictionary.Add(new TestClass {MyProperty = 1}, new ValueClass {MyProperty = 1});
        dictionary.Add(new TestClass {MyProperty = 2}, new ValueClass {MyProperty = 2});
        dictionary.Add(new TestClass {MyProperty = 3}, new ValueClass {MyProperty = 3});
        dictionary.Add(new TestClass {MyProperty = 4}, new ValueClass {MyProperty = 4});
        dictionary.Add(new TestClass {MyProperty = 5}, new ValueClass {MyProperty = 5});
        dictionary.Add(new TestClass {MyProperty = 6}, new ValueClass {MyProperty = 6});
    }
```

Key and Value Class:

```
namespace HashDictionaryTest
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }

        public override int GetHashCode() {
            return MyProperty;
        }
    }

}

namespace HashDictionaryTest
{
    public class ValueClass
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }

        public override int GetHashCode() {
            return MyProperty;
        }
    }

}
```

I am using the dotnet core 2.2 on Ubuntu. I did this test out of curiosity only. However, to my surprise, I got **KeyNotFoundException**.

I expected to receive the wrong values. However, I received the exception as mentioned above.

What I want to know is, why we got this error? What is the best practice in generating the HashCode so that we can avoid such issues?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].  Missing def for `ValueClass`

Comment: Thank You @JohnB I added the complete code. Let me know if I am missing something. Also clarified my question.

Comment: this is a weird bit of code you have.  you're messing around with keys then expecting them to somehow magically be findable again?  maybe explain what your goal is...

Comment: The Dictionary does not support mutation of the keys https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007296/c-sharp-dictionary-and-mutable-keys

Comment: try messing around with the `Value` property instead... not the `Key`

Comment: @JohnB, I wanted to know two things. 1. Why it gave "KeyNotFound" vs giving me the wrong value? I get that now. 2. What is the best practice here if I want to write GetHashCode()? Due to the confidentiality agreement, I cannot reveal the real business requirements.

Comment: read it, it is good article : https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1255596/Overriding-Equals-GetHashCode-Laconically-in-CShar

Comment: Actually supporting equality is a mess.  In addition to `GetHashCode`, You'll also want to implement `IEquatable<TestClass>`, override `Equals(object)`, implement `Equals(TestClass)`, implement `operator==`, and implement `operator!=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***KeyNotFoundException ... Why?***

The distilled, core reason is that the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods are inconsistent. This situation is fixed by doing 2 things:

- Override `Equals` in `TestClass`
- Never modify a dictionary during iteration

  - It's that the key object/value is being modified

---

**`GetHashCode` - `Equals` disconnect**

- [... GetHashCode is not expected to change over the lifecycle of the object.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509316/keynotfoundexception-in-c-sharp-dictionary-after-changing-property-value-based-o#comment95822315_54509376)  AND  [do not use values that are subject to change while calculating `GetHashCode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509316/keynotfoundexception-in-c-sharp-dictionary-after-changing-property-value-based-o/54509376?noredirect=1#comment95822349_54509376)

  - Not exactly. The problem is a changing hash code while equality does not change.
  - MSDN says: *The GetHashCode() method for an object must consistently return the same hash code as long as there is no modification to the object state that determines the return value of the object's System.Object.Equals method*

---

**`TestClass.Equals`**

I say `TestClass` because that is the dictionary key. But this applies to `ValueClass` too.

A class' `Equals` and `GetHashCode` ***must*** be consistent. When overriding either but not both then they are not consistent. We all know "if you override `Equals` also override `GetHashCode`". We never override `GetHashCode` yet seem to get away with it. Hear me now and believe me the first time you implement `IEqualityComparer` and `IEquatable` - always override both.

---

**Iterating Dictionary**

Do not add or delete an element, modify a key, nor modify a value (sometimes) *during iteration*.

- [Editing Dictionary Values ... in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1070766/463206)  - It hits on some technical reasons a dictionary entry cannot safely be modified during iteration
- [MSDN Dictionary doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [Can change value during iteration](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c98e9d32-7f06-4b3a-8917-8b58eee31e58/change-dictionary-values-while-iterating?forum=netfxbcl)  - The dictionary "value", not the key's value
- [Well, not in every case](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/updating-dictionary-elements-while-iterating1)

---

**GetHashCode**

- [MSDN GetHashCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.7.2)

  - *Do not use the hash code as the key to retrieve an object from a keyed collection.*
  - *Do not test for equality of hash codes to determine whether two objects are equal*

The OP code may not be doing this literally but certainly virtually because there is no Equals override.

[Here is a neat hash algorithm from C# demi god Eric Lipper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/463206)

Answer (score 5):

> What I want to know is, why we got this error?

There are *guidelines* for GetHashCode, and there are *rules*.  If you violate the guidelines, you get lousy performance. If you violate the *rules*, things break.

You are violating the *rules*. One of the *rules* of GetHashCode is *while an object is in a dictionary, its hash code must not change.* Another rule is that *equal objects must have equal hash codes*.

You've violated the rules, and so things are broken. That's your fault; don't violate the rules.

> What is the best practice in generating the HashCode so that we can avoid such issues?

For a list of the rules and guidelines, see:

https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank You.

Comment: @RipalBarot: You're welcome! My goal for writing that article was to get all the rules in one place for easy consumption, because there are a lot of developers like you who don't know exactly what the rules are and wind up in trouble as a result. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

That is the expected behavior with your code. Then what is your wrong with your code?

Look at your Key Class. You are overriding your `GetHashCode()` and on top of that you are using a mutable value to calculate the `GetHashCode()` method (very very bad :( ).

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return MyProperty;
    }
}
```

The look up in the implementation of the Dictionary uses `GetHashCode()` of the inserted object. At the time of insertion of your object your `GetHashCode()` returned some value and that object got inserted into some `bucket`. However, after you changed your `MyProperty`; `GetHashCode()` does not return the same value therefore it can not be look-ed up any more

This is where the lookup occurs

```
Console.WriteLine($"{dict[k].MyProperty} - {k.MyProperty}");
```

`dict[k]` already had its `MyProperty` changed therefore `GetHashCode()` does not return the value when the object first added to the dictionary.

Ant another really important thing is to keep in mind that when you override `GetHashCode()` then override `Equals()` as well. The inverse is true too!

Comment: +1 for the answer. What is the best practice for GetHashCode()? How would you generate the hashcode in such scenario?

Comment: `GetHashCode()` is not supposed to use mutable data to calculate hash. In your case you can make `MyProperty` into immutable.

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü He is not using a mutable type for hashcode. `int` is immutable. The problem is that a property taking part in `GetHashCode` is not expected to change over the lifecycle of the object.

Comment: @swdon, I would check the definition of mutable in your case :) He is using some `int` value at the insertion time then magically that `int` value is `changed` into another thing. Keyword being change. By the way where in my answer did I use `mutable type`?

Comment: I guess what you meant is along the lines of remove the setter for `MyProperty`, set `MyProperty` in the constructor and then override `GetHashCode()` like `return MyProperty.GetHashCode()`.

Comment: @swdon, What I meant is do not use values that are subject to change while calculating `GetHashCode()`

Comment: @radarbob, I am not sure if you are commenting on my answer? Or some other users deleted comments?

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü, sorry for the confusion. I removed my comments into an answer